# Moq Returns with multiple Linq Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq

I have the following method within a repository that I am trying to Mock:

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(
      Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
      Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
      string includeProperties = "")
```

I've setup the following:

```
mockContactNumberRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ContactNumber, bool>>>(), 
    It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<ContactNumber>, IOrderedQueryable<ContactNumber>>>(),
    It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(new Func<Expression<Func<ContactNumber, bool>>, 
        IQueryable<ContactNumber>>(ex => _contactNumbers.Where(ex.Compile()).AsQueryable()));
```

When running the unit test I receive an error message about Parameter count mismatch.  I understand this is because the `Returns` is only specifying the first parameter but I am unsure how to specify the further parameters.

I've found many questions that ask similar questions but not found one with multiple lambda expressions.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetAll` method takes three arguments and returns an `IEnumerable<TEntity>`.  The `valueFunction` parameter in `Returns` needs to have a matching signature and return type.  The `valueFunction` parameter in your example only has two input arguments and the second argument does not match any of the argument types passed to `GetAll`.  It should look something like this (I don't have the benefit of the compiler checking my syntax but I think what I have here should be correct):

```
mockContactNumberRepository
.Setup(x => 
    x
    .GetAll(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ContactNumber, bool>>>(), 
        It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<ContactNumber>, IOrderedQueryable<ContactNumber>>>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()))
.Returns(new Func<
    Expression<Func<ContactNumber, bool>>, 
    Func<IQueryable<ContactNumber>, IOrderedQueryable<ContactNumber>>,
    string,
    IEnumerable<TEntity>>((arg1, arg2, arg3) => 
        {
            // arg1 is Expression<Func<ContactNumber, bool>>
            // arg2 is Func<IQueryable<ContactNumber>, IOrderedQueryable<ContactNumber>>
            // arg3 is string
            // Do something here and return an IEnumerable<TEntity>
        }));
```