# Moq with exact Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to test a Get method of a repository. The signature is as follows:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
```

This method is usually invoked in the following manner:

```
Department targetDepartment =
            _departmentRepository.Get(department => department.Id == departmentId).FirstOrDefault();
```

It works fine with real data, it's when I try to setup this method to return a specific 'Department' with a specific lambda where the problems begin.

So far, I have tried many ways to mock it and here are some of them:

1)

```
Expression<Func<Department, bool>> filterExpression2 = d => d.Id == DepartmentId;

_departmentRepositoryMock.Setup(repo => repo.Get(
    It.Is<Expression<Func<Department, bool>>>(y => filterExpression2.Compile()(firstDepartment)),
    null, 
    It.IsAny<string>()))
                         .Returns(new List<Department>() { firstDepartment }.AsQueryable());
```

2)

```
Expression<Func<Department, bool>> filterExpression2 = d => d.Id == DepartmentId;

_departmentRepositoryMock.Setup(repo => repo.Get(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Department, bool>>>(),
    null, 
    It.IsAny<string>()))
                         .Returns(new List<Department>() { firstDepartment }.Where(filterExpression2.Compile()).AsQueryable());
```

I saw many similar questions but somehow none of them is helpful.

What I am trying to do is to force the mocked repository to return a specific Department depending on the 'Id' parameter sent to the lambda.

I am aware of many responses using `It.IsAny`, but that it's not what I want as it would trigger a match on literally any expression passed into the Get method.

Can anyone help me, or at least push me in the right direction?

Comment: And also matches closely to this [Moq Returns with multiple Linq Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35569731/5233410)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried the following minimal example and was able pass test. Pay attention to the setup and returns.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest11 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        //Arrange
        //fake data
        var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(id => new Department { Id = id }).ToList();

        var mock = new Mock<IRepository<Department>>();

        mock
            .Setup(repo => repo.Get(
                It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Department, bool>>>(),
                null,
                It.IsAny<string>())
            )
            .Returns(
                (
                    Expression<Func<Department, bool>> filter,
                    Func<IQueryable<Department>, IOrderedQueryable<Department>> orderBy,
                    string includeProperties
                ) => {
                    var func = filter.Compile();
                    var result = list.Where(func);

                    if (orderBy != null) {
                        result = orderBy(result.AsQueryable());
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            );

        var sut = new MyClass(mock.Object);

        var departmentId = 2;

        //Act
        var actual = sut.GetDepartment(departmentId);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, list[departmentId - 1]);

    }


    public class MyClass {
        private readonly IRepository<Department> _departmentRepository;

        public MyClass(IRepository<Department> repository) {
            this._departmentRepository = repository;
        }

        public Department GetDepartment(int departmentId) {
            Department targetDepartment = _departmentRepository.Get(department => department.Id == departmentId).FirstOrDefault();

            return targetDepartment;
        }
    }

    public class Department {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepository<TEntity> {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = ""
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't quite what I am looking for - it still uses IsAny. Ideally I would like something like this:

Comment: _departmentRepositoryMock.Setup(repo => repo.Get(x => x.Id == DepartmentId, null, String.Empty))
                .Returns(new List<Department>() {firstDepartment});